# Accessibility error: Facebook JS SDK generates iframes with no title attributes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, accessibility

I'm using the HTML5 implementation of the Like button which uses this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<%= locals[:appId] %>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This generates two iframes in the page:

```
<div>
  <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_http" name="fb_xdm_frame_http" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=18#channel=f118ae5cc&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fau0078.local%3A4567&amp;channel_path=%2FTE01_home_page_mobile.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df324a069cc%26" tabindex="-1"></iframe>    
  <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_https" name="fb_xdm_frame_https" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=18#channel=f118ae5cc&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fau0078.local%3A4567&amp;channel_path=%2FTE01_home_page_mobile.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df324a069cc%26" tabindex="-1"></iframe>    
</div>
```

Neither of these iframes has a `title` attribute, so they are causing accessibility errors. Any idea how I get around this?

Comment: Report it as a bug at the following link.
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=accessibility

Answer (score 0):

According to [WebAIM's](http://webaim.org/techniques/frames/#iframe) write-up on iframes, the main accessibility issue is that there is no content between the iframe tags.

> When using iframes, you should ensure that the alternative content (the content between the iframe tags) is useful.

The title attribute **can** be used for additional information, but isn't as important as including useful information as alternative content, even if it is just an alternate link to the content itself.